# SQL Server Replication Process Account Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication, database-administration

As per below image, I am Configuring the Transactional Replication in SQL Server 2008 R2.

[image]

I need to give process account and password.

I tried to provide the account as the account from which i login for ex "sa"
and password is password for "sa".

It fails as it is not a correct account.

Please help me.(If i need to provide any account please provide me detail how to find that account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your **Windows account** name and password, not your database user and password.